# How to configure Django url to point to a specific section in the page?

Tags: django, url, web-applications

I'm trying to configure a url in Django to let it point to a specific section in certain page.
Let's say I have this in my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", mywebsite.views.home, name="home"),]
```

I'm already awared of that I can use `"{% url 'home' %}"` in my templates to go to this page.
However, I'm wondering that is it possible to go directly to the #experience section in my homepage with modifications on this url configuration?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can do that. First you need to make sure you have an anchor tag as:

```
<a name="experience"></a>
```

in your homepage.
Then you can use:

```
"{% url 'home' %}#experience"
```

To directly go to that section of your homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Sanip 's suggestion, the anchor tag worked in my case if it was placed under ID, not Name. Like so:

```
<a id="experience">Text</a>
```